# Count all non-zero elements in the 3D matrix, but for each plane in dimension 2

Tags: python, linear-algebra, torch

I would like to perform the same thing that this function does but in memory and I don't really know how to do it.

Operation: the input is a scan which consists of superimposed images which results in a dimension (Height, Width, Number of images), I would like to obtain a vector with dimension (Number of images) using a single operation where the values will be non-zero elements for each image in scan.

The best I was able to do was iterate through each of the image.

```
def get_plane_where_tumor_is_thelargest_v2(brain_scan_label: torch.Tensor):
    slices_areas = torch.zeros(brain_scan_label.shape[-1])
    for i in range(brain_scan_label.shape[-1]):
        slices_areas[i] = brain_scan_label[:, :, i].count_nonzero()
        
    return slices_areas.argmax()
```

Comment: Glad to hear you solved it! Please don't include answers in questions. Instead, post it as an answer—you can even mark your own answer as accepted!